# Hook for redraw event in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Is there a way to add a *redraw callback* to a *live* screen object, i.e. not via inheritance?

---

*Reasoning*:
I want to draw an overlay from an extension for widget sdk (substituting jumpy position:fixed), so the screen is created by the bbwp stub.

I can get it by

```
Ui.getUiEngine().getActiveScreen()
```

and draw on it quite nicely, but I need a way to redraw when appropriate.

---

*Note*:
I've abandoned the approach to push the overlay as a screen, because i couldn't make it transparent / find a way to pass events through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push the overlay as a screen, you should be able to make it's background transparent by overriding the paintBackground() method as follows:

```
// Make background transparent
protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) {
    XYRect xy = graphics.getClippingRect();
    graphics.pushContext(xy, 0, 0);
    graphics.setGlobalAlpha(0);
    graphics.setColor(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(xy.x, xy.y, xy.width, xy.height);
    graphics.popContext();
}
```

Then, to pass touch events through, override the following method and return -1 if you don't want your screen to handle the touch event:

```
public int getFieldAtLocation(int x, int y) {
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow